# Can't install reactstrap to visual studio code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

npm i reactstrap
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (reactstrap)
npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, reactstrap)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!   react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.7.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!     reactstrap@"8.7.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-12T17_49_58_823Z-debug.log

Comment: I have provided a solution. Let me know if you need more help mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you open your React Project in VSCode. Do (*Ctrl+ `* [That is press CTRL and tilt key on keyborad] ) this will open a **VSCode's Integrated terminal**.

Then install **reactstrap** from using npm by doing:

```
npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom
```

Once done, check your `package.json` file and see whether the dependencies are installed.

Integrated Terminal Demo:

[image: Integrated Terminal]

Comment: I did what they said but I still get the same error. The reactstrap is not in package.json.

Comment: Are other dependencies installed correctly. For instance try to install react-icons and let me know what happened : npm install react-icons --save

Comment: Dear Brother Arif, Open you package.json file and tell me what is your current version of "react" and "react-dom" under "dependencies"?

Comment: "name": "intro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },

Comment: Try  with the following dependencies. Use these
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },

And then do npm install and again try to install your reactstrap with npm install reactstrap

Comment: Let me know if this will work.  If not we'll go with another solution. Stay happy brother, I am here to help. Don't worry. We will make it work. InshaAllah :)

Comment: you solved my problem thank you very much but I got this warning. npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

Comment: npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated @types/testing-library__dom@7.5.0: This is a stub types definition. testing-library__dom provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.2: Please update to latest version

Comment: Thank you very much for sparing your time for me, you solved my problem. You are the best brother btw <3

Comment: It would be best if you click on the tick icon at the start of my answer and also rate by clicking on up triangular icon. This will motivate me to help more and more people on the internet. Will get back to you on Popper.js thing. That is a small thing. Mean while if you go the official website of reactstrap, and read the documentation you will find a popper link which you need to include inside your index.html file in your src folder. And then you are good to go :) Almighty bless you:)  Fee AmaanilLah Brother :)

Comment: yes, i did "import"